# Convert base64 encoding to pdf

Tags: c#

I tried multiple solution but every time I am getting error that pdf can not be open. This is the edited code with actual data stream that need to be converted in .pdf.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string base64BinaryStr = "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";

            byte[] sPDFDecoded = Convert.FromBase64String(base64BinaryStr);




            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(@"c:\Users\u316383\Documents\pdf9.pdf", FileMode.CreateNew));
            writer.Write(sPDFDecoded);

            string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sPDFDecoded);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is that rather short base64 string a valid PDF file? Seems short even for a header.

Comment: actual one is really big but this one is also a valid file as i have checked it.String "s" is giving correct.if you want I can give entire string.I checked the string via "http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp"

Comment: Your input string is 12 characters long which means 8 bytes as input PDF. That's not likely to be correct.

Comment: If actual string can help:"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"

Comment: learn about `using` or write to the file with `File.WriteAllBytes(path, data)` - it's not going to fix your issue and we can't see it without the actual PDF data

Comment: The string in your comment doesn't decode to a proper PDF. Your string's decode starts with `'\5-Z` and PDF documents start with `%PDF-1.4`

Comment: I have pasted and modified the question as per suggestion.I hope this helps.

Comment: @StenPetrov-Thanks..You are right.i am given wrong Binary .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Was given the wrong string. It was simple, for any other reference my code was:

```cs
byte[] sPDFDecoded = Convert.FromBase64String(base64BinaryStr);
    
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\Users\u316383\Documents\pdf8.pdf", sPDFDecoded);
```

Thanks all.

Comment: I was trying to decode using  `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String())`. Writing the bytes to file, rather than a string, resolved my issue.